# Error installing VS2008 on virtualbox

Tags: visual-studio, installation, virtualization, virtualbox

This is the fifth time now, tried different machines, different drive sizes,even tried both Vista and XP, nothing seems to work.

I installed a virtualbox VM.  Set up an OS, then try to set up VS2008.

And then the VS2008 installation crashes with the following error log

```
[04/13/09,14:27:31] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 is not installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Document Explorer 2008 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Web Authoring Component was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 3.5 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for the Microsoft Office system (version 3.0 Runtime) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Design Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 For Devices was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2 for Pocket PC was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2 for Smartphone was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Device Emulator version 3.0 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Headers and Libraries (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Win32 Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 .NET Framework Tools (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 SDK Reference Assemblies and IntelliSense (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/13/09,14:27:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard was not attempted to be installed
```

My VM typically (I tried this a lot) has a 20 GB disk and 700MB ram allotted.  Everything else is default.

Anyone have any similar problems or can at least help me out with whats going on?

Comment: What configurations did the VM OS have? What service packs, framework installs, etc?

Comment: The second line indicates that .NET 3.5 is not installed, though VS2008 setup should handle that....  have you confirmed that your guest OS has internet access?

Comment: Hmm...no it doesn't, I thought that the VS2008 installer came bundled with the .net 3.5 installation

Answer (score 2):

Sound like a problem with virtualbox, you can try to install everything on VPC then [convert the vhd to vdi.](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=1966)

Comment: Thanks, but this is a brand new installation and the disk is a vdi already.  Everything is brand new.

Comment: I know but for some strange reason MSI have problems with VMs (I saw the same issue with old VPC), again start fresh build a VHD then convert and work with the VDI.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying use a vhd (how to do that?) then re-install everything to that and then convert to vdi?

Comment: yes, download free VirtualPC, create a VM on it (XP only) install everything (Visual Studio etc) then take the created VHD and convert it.